# No implementation found for long org.tensorflow.contrib.android.RunStats.allocate()

Tags: android, tensorflow, tensorflow-android

My local Logcat is below

```
04-27 14:05:47.501 16780-16780/com.cogitator.imagesearchtensorflowandroid D/ViewRootImpl:ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0 04-27 14:05:47.641 16780-16780/com.cogitator.imagesearchtensorflowandroid D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
04-27 14:05:47.701 16780-16780/com.cogitator.imagesearchtensorflowandroid D/SecWifiDisplayUtil: Metadata value : none
04-27 14:05:47.711 16780-16780/com.cogitator.imagesearchtensorflowandroid D/SensorManager: registerListener :: 0, ICM20610 Acceleration Sensor, 200000, 0,  
04-27 14:05:47.721 16780-16822/com.cogitator.imagesearchtensorflowandroid I/TAG: Reading labels from: labels.txt
04-27 14:05:47.731 16780-16822/com.cogitator.imagesearchtensorflowandroid I/System.out: >  flipflops
>  gown
>  kurta
>  polo
>  shirt
>  shoe
>  suit
>  summerdress
>  top
>  tshirt
>  white_shirt
04-27 14:05:47.731 16780-16822/com.cogitator.imagesearchtensorflowandroid I/TensorFlowInferenceInterface: Checking to see if TensorFlow native methods are already loaded

04-27 14:05:47.741 16780-16822/com.cogitator.imagesearchtensorflowandroid E/art: No implementation found for long org.tensorflow.contrib.android.RunStats.allocate() (tried Java_org_tensorflow_contrib_android_RunStats_allocate and Java_org_tensorflow_contrib_android_RunStats_allocate__)

04-27 14:05:47.741 16780-16822/com.cogitator.imagesearchtensorflowandroid I/TensorFlowInferenceInterface: TensorFlow native methods not found, attempting to load via tensorflow_inference
04-27 14:05:47.821 16780-16822/com.cogitator.imagesearchtensorflowandroid I/TensorFlowInferenceInterface: Successfully loaded TensorFlow native methods (RunStats error may be ignored)
04-27 14:05:47.961 16780-16822/com.cogitator.imagesearchtensorflowandroid I/TensorFlowInferenceInterface: Model load took 59ms, TensorFlow version: 1.7.0
Successfully loaded model from 'file:///android_asset/graph.pb'
```

Comment: did you find a solution for this ?

Comment: Not yet. I searches through blogs and websites, but couldn’t get it.

Comment: taking a second look at your logcat ! it seems that the error is ignored so you don't have anything to worry about since this appeared after your error : `Successfully loaded TensorFlow native methods (RunStats error may be ignored)`

Comment: I get the same error: No implementation found for long org.tensorflow.contrib.android.RunStats.allocate(), 
but the model is loaded successfully. Is it a big issue??